# Android app crashes on onClickListener

Tags: android

I have this app which is a simple lottery system but whenever I try pressing one of the buttons the app freezes then crashes and I don't know why. The program doesn't give me errors so it's really confusing. I saw some things about it being a problem with the layout but I can't figure out what it is. I will answer the page Layout in a comment under the question. Thanks in advance.

Here's the page script:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.icu.text.NumberFormat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import javax.xml.transform.Result;

public class Lottery extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button Check, Random;
    EditText User1;
    TextView Balance2, ResultText;
    int  Balance1 = 500;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lottery);
        Check = (Button)findViewById(R.id.CheckNumbers);
        Random = (Button)findViewById(R.id.RandomNumber);
        User1 = findViewById(R.id.PickNumber);
        Balance2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Balance);
        ResultText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Result);
        ResultText.setVisibility(View.GONE);

       Balance2.setText("Balance: $500");

        Check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int User=Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(User1));
                if(User1.toString().trim().equals("")){
                    ResultText.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    ResultText.setText("Please Enter a Number");
                    ResultText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
                else if(User > 100 || User < 1){
                    ResultText.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    ResultText.setText("Please Enter a Number between 1 and 100");
                    ResultText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                else {
                    int answer = (int)((Math.random()*100)+1);
                    int placeholder = answer % 10;
                    int AnswerTens = (answer - placeholder)/10;
                    int AnswerOnes = placeholder;
                    placeholder = User %10;
                    int UserTens = (User- placeholder)/10;
                    int UserOnes = placeholder;

                    if(User == answer){
                        ResultText.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                        ResultText.setText("Correct!!! The Number was "+User+" $1000 has been added to your account");
                        ResultText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Balance1 += 1000;
                        Balance2.setText("Balance: $ "+  Balance1);
                    }
                    else if((UserTens == AnswerOnes)&&(UserOnes == AnswerTens)){
                        ResultText.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                        ResultText.setText(" Somewhat Correct! The digit were correct but in the wrong order The answer was "+answer+" $500 has been added to your account");
                        ResultText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Balance1 += 500;
                        Balance2.setText("Balance: $ "+  Balance1);
                    }
                    else if((UserTens == AnswerTens)|| (UserTens == AnswerOnes)||(UserOnes == AnswerOnes)||(UserOnes==AnswerTens)){
                        ResultText.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                        ResultText.setText("Kinda Correct! One digit was  correct The answer was "+answer+" $100 has been added to your account");
                        ResultText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Balance1 += 100;
                        Balance2.setText("Balance: $ "+  Balance1);
                    }
                    else{
                        ResultText.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                        ResultText.setText("Incorrect the Number was "+answer);
                        ResultText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }


                }
            }
        });
        Random.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               int answer = (int)((Math.random()*100)+1);

                User1.setText(answer);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: and here's is the page layout code in case you want it:

Comment: It is not a `script` but this is java code. Could you post your error?

Comment: Look in the logcat to find the crash stack trace and post it here too. Which button causes the crash? https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/stacktraces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a couple possible causes for a crash. As @Siros mentioned, you need to use `String.valueOf(answer)` in your call to `setText`

In addition, to get the string from an `EditText` you have to call `User1.getText().toString()`. Calling `User1.toString()` will return something like `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{cab8e45 VFED..CL. ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f08003e app:id/editText}`, which can definitely not be parsed as an integer.

Calling `Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(User1));` will always crash with a `NumberFormatException` (since the string it's trying to parse is like the one above).

When you call `Integer.parseInt(string);` it will throw an exception if the string is not a valid integer (e.g. a blank string, or `0.1.2.3`). You will see a stack trace that looks something like this:

```
Process: com.project.testproject, PID: 30357
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.project.testproject/com.project.testproject.MainActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{8c2c99a VFED..CL. ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f08003e app:id/editText}"
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{8c2c99a VFED..CL. ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f08003e app:id/editText}"
    at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
    at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:410)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:367)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
    at com.project.testproject.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
```

You may want to use something like this:

```
String UserString = User1.getText().toString();

if( UserString.trim().isEmpty() ) {
    //handle empty string
}
else {
    try {
       int User = Integer.parseInt(UserString);

       // Handle valid number cases
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException ne) {
      // handle invalid entry
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this :

```java
User1.setText(answer);
```

To this :

```js
User1.setText(String.valueOf(answer));
```

Comment: To elaborate, when you pass an int to a view, it thinks its a reference to a resource defined in xml. Then if it can't find it, it will crash. If you actually want the view to display the number, convert it to a string first.

Comment: Thank you soo much I've been trying to figure this out for ages!

Comment: Just as a side question do you know what is wrong with the the 
        Check.setOnClickListener button, it also freezes.